# Fully Defined Bijective Functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1. For each of the functions below, verify whether they are fully-defined bijections. In each case, determine the definition domain and the range.

   $f:\mathbb N→\mathbb N, f(n) = (n−1)^2 − 1$

(N is natural numbers).

First I need to decide if it is fully defined which means that Def Domain = Domain. I can see that the DefDom is {$1,2,...$} but what is the domain?

Then I need to check if its injective. To do that I take two arbritary numbers $n$ and $n'$ and do $f(n) = f(n')$ After solving, I find that $n = n'$, so it's injective.

Then I need to check if its surjective. To do that I have to make sure the Range = Counter domain. The counter domain is all the numbers {$1,2...$}. But how do I find the range?

Can someone please give the answer to this with an explanation?

Thank you!!

Comment: The range is the set of numbers that $f(n)$ could possibly equal. It is not hard to find a number $k$ such that $f(n)\neq k$ for all $n$, and such a number would be a counterexample to surjectivity.

Comment: If the thing is called $f\colon \color{red}{\Bbb N}\to\Bbb N$, then the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb N$. But what s a Def domain and a Counter domain?

Comment: Also, isn't $f(1)=-1\notin\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: As written, $f(1)=0^2-1=-1\not \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: So would the def Domain then be from {3,4,5,6....}?

Comment: I still need help